# How to migrate from redux 'connect' to hooks 'useDispatch' and 'useSelector'?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm not sure how to migrate from redux to hooks, as far as dispatching actions and retrieving state from store, as there are no official guides provided. Is this way correct?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'
import { actions, selectors } from 'data'
import TemplateComponent from './template'

const areaSelectors = selectors.components.areas
const modalActions = actions.modals

const selectAllAreas = createSelector(
  areaSelectors.getAdminAreas,
  areaSelectors.getGuestAreas,
  (adminAreas, guestAreas) => adminAreas.concat(guestAreas)
)

const ContainerComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const allAreas = useSelector(selectAllAreas)
  const adminAreas = useSelector(areaSelectors.getAdminAreas)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      modalActions.showModal('AreaAddGuest')
    )
  }, [dispatch])

  const passedProps = {
    allAreas,
    adminAreas
  }

  return <TemplateComponent {...passedProps} />
}

export default ContainerComponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selecting part seems correct,

the part with the dispatch doesn't.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the effect there, but the useDispatch is simple. It will give you a dispatch function, which you can then use to do `dispatch(mdalActions.showModal('AreaAddGuest'))` when you need that done.

The `}, [dispatch])` part in the useEffect just tells useEffect to run whenever the dispatch function changes, which means probably never, but it also highly depend on the implementation. That seems almost certainly wrong.

If you can, post the code before adding the hooks, to see what the original was.

Also note that it's by no means necessary to rewrite code to use hooks. If the classes ever become obsoleted, it will most likely be far in the future.